# merge two dataframes pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading 2 dfs using:

```
extra = pd.read_csv('table1.txt', sep = '\s+')
data = pd.read_csv('table2.dat', sep = '\s+')
```

The output of `extra.info()` is:

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 11528 entries, 0 to 11527
Data columns:
a     11528  non-null values
key   11528  non-null values
c     11528  non-null values
d     11528  non-null values
e     11528  non-null values
f     11528  non-null values
g     11528  non-null values
h     11528  non-null values
i     11528  non-null values
j     11528  non-null values
k     11528  non-null values
dtypes: float64(11)None
```

The output of `data.info()` is:

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 11528 entries, 0 to 11527
Data columns:
1      11528  non-null values
2      11528  non-null values
3      11528  non-null values
key    11528  non-null values
5      11528  non-null values
...
79     11528  non-null values
80     11528  non-null values
81     11528  non-null values
dtypes: float64(80), int64(1)None
```

So both of these 2 dfs have `11528 rows` and they have a common column called: `key`

I merged these 2 dfs using:

```
result = pd.merge(data, extra, on='key', sort = False)
```

And the output of `result.info()` is:

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 11926 entries, 0 to 11925
Data columns:
1    11926  non-null values
2    11926  non-null values
3    11926  non-null values
key  11926  non-null values
5    11926  non-null values
6    11926  non-null values
...
80   11926  non-null values
81   11926  non-null values
a    11926  non-null values
b    11926  non-null values
...    
j    11926  non-null values
k    11926  non-null values
dtypes: float64(90), int64(1)None
```

Obviously there is something wrong, as the new merged df, `result` has `11926 rows`.

Can someone please explain what's happening and what is the correct way to write this down?

Thanks!

### Example

```
df1 = 1 key 3 4
    1 8 90 5 11
    2 7 60 2 30
    3 3 70 3 26
    4 7 60 2 10

df2 = 5 6 key 7
    1 3 2 90 17
    2 9 3 60 42
    3 6 4 70 17
    4 1 5 60 23
```

My desired output is:

```
1 key 3 4 5 6 7 
1 8 90 5 11 3 2 17
2 7 60 2 30 9 3 42
3 3 70 3 26 6 4 17
4 7 60 2 10 1 5 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is you have duplicate values of `key` in one or both dataframes.  So if `data` has `key1` in it 5 times, and `extra` has `key1` in it 2 times, then you will have 10 entries for `key1` when you merge the two dataframes on the key column.

The way out of this is:

```
# delete the common column in one of the data frames
del extra['key']

# join
result = data.join(extra)
```

Comment: Just to make it clearer, the column `key` is the same in both dfs. And I am using it to merge the 2 dfs. What you are saying is that the `column key` has duplicates of a certain `value` so when merged they will be entered twice. Right? How can I fix it?

Comment: You have to state what *fixed* means to you, have you tried passing `how='left'` to `merge`

Comment: Charlie you are right, because when I write `sort = True` then I can see the that there are duplicates. @EdChum, I wrote a small example of the output I want.

Comment: @po6 you've not stated whether passing `how='left'` worked or not

Comment: @EdChum, no it did not work. The resultant df still has `11926 rows`.

Comment: The left join shouldn't make a difference.  I think what you actually want to do may be to join on the index, in which case you will have the same number of output rows as input.  And to do that, you can just write data.join(extra)

Comment: @po6 can you try `extra.combine_first(data)` I think this should work

Comment: @CharlieHaley, `data.join(extra)` raised an error: `Exception: columns overlap: array(['key'], dtype=object)`

Comment: @EdChum, it worked. The output df has `11528 rows` but now the order of the columns has changed! `Data columns:
1                 11528  non-null values
10                11528  non-null values
...
2                 11528  non-null values
20                11528  non-null values
...
`

Comment: The `data columns` in order are: `1 10 11 12 ... 2 20 21 22 ... `

Comment: I have to caution you that I'm not sure this is what you want, `combine_first` uses the other df to fill in the missing column values, it doesn't merge on the key as such.

Comment: @EdChum according to the documentation, `combine_first` is the `union` of 2 dfs which is exactly what I want since the common column in both dfs have the same order (as in the example I wrote above). My only concern now is to fix the order of the columns. I don't want to  change the original order.

Comment: @po6 not sure why it did that you could use fancy indexing to fix it so `col_list = extra.columns | data.columns` `merged = merged.ix[:,col_list]`

Comment: Thanks for your help @EdChum, I ended up deleting the common column by `del extra['key']` and then I joined the 2 dfs using `result = data.join(extra)`. It works perfectly fine! :)